# Google maps : Finding polygon by Id

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, polygon, google-maps-engine

Hi I have a polygon below :

```
var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
              paths: coords,
              id : 123,
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
              strokeWeight: 1,
              fillColor: '#FF0000',
              fillOpacity: 0.35
            });

polygon.setMap(globalMap);
```

I attached an **id** property to it so i can refer to it later on, the problem is. How do I find that same polygon and trigger an event? like a change color or something?

```
function changePolygonColor(){
//refer to the polygon with id 123 (this is my question)

//change its color
polygon.fillColor = '#00FF00';
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to trigger an event after finding the polygon with a specific `id`.

Now, one thing you can do is just add an event listener to the `polygon` and refer to the polygon using the `this` context. You can then trigger the change of colour accordingly (for example):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function (event) {
  alert(this.id);
  //Once you have the id here, you can trigger the color change
});
```

In your case however, if you don't want to trigger the color change on a specific even listener that can be added to the `polygon`. You could simply store the polygons in a polygon array and loop through them in your specific function that changes the colors. So you could try something like this (untested):

```
var polygonArray = []; //Have a global array of polygon elements
polygonArray.push(polygon); //Push your polygons as you create them into this polygon array

...

function changePolygonColor(){
 //refer to the polygon with id 123 (this is my question)
 //Loop through the polygon array
  for (var i = 0; i < polygonArray.length; i++) {
   if(polygonArray[i].id == 123) //Or whatever that you require
     {
       //change its color 
       polygon[i].fillColor = '#00FF00';
     }
  }
}
```

You might also want to check some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208965/google-map-add-click-listener-to-each-polygon) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333653/google-maps-api-v3-why-no-context-with-events) [Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962948/how-can-i-get-the-polygon-object-in-google-maps-when-a-path-changed) on a similar issue. Hope this gets you started in the right direction.